# Get element attribute and replace

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, title

I am using boostrap popover to replace tooltip. And for now i got this

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('[title]').attr("data-rel", "tooltip");
    var titlePopover = $("[data-rel='tooltip']").attr("title");
    $("[data-rel='tooltip']").removeAttr('title').attr("data-placement", "top").attr("data-content", titlePopover);


    var showPopover = function() {
        $(this).popover('show');
    };
    var hidePopover = function() {
        $(this).popover('hide');
    };
    $("[data-rel='tooltip']").popover({
        trigger: 'manual'
    }).click(showPopover).hover(showPopover, hidePopover);

});
```

And  HTML

```
 <p title="THIS IS STEP 1">STEP 1</p>
 <p title="THIS IS STEP 2">STEP 2</p>
 <p title="THIS IS STEP 3">STEP 3</p>
 <p title="THIS IS STEP 4">STEP 4</p>
```

This is working ok, but the problem now every element have same title?

Here is working fiddle 
http://www.bootply.com/IUhlrnoHG5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are specifying the title of first `h1` only. You can use [.attr( attributeName, function )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

Use

```
$("[data-rel='tooltip']")
    .attr("data-placement", "top")
    .attr("data-content", function() {
        return this.title;  //return $(this).attr("title") 
    })
    .removeAttr('title');
```

instead of

```
var titlePopover = $("[data-rel='tooltip']").attr("title");
$("[data-rel='tooltip']").removeAttr('title').attr("data-placement", "top").attr("data-content", titlePopover);
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/EqnL1GPP8r)